# Adobe AIR : Save loaded data into a directory

Tags: javascript, air, adobe

Im developing an application that loads some datas ( Images , sounds , texts ) into application and show it , i want to create some Cache-like system to prevent to re-load datas that already loaded. Im okey with the texts , I Did that.

all i want is get the path that contain current loaded image.
is there a way to find the path of loaded data , then i can copy the temp file to my cache and when i want to reload data , check for existing datas and show cached or load new data and cache it again ?

Comment: How do you want the caching system works? Does it requires to save the cache even you completely terminate the app and retrieve it the next time you open it?

Comment: Thnx for reply , no , cache will not terminate till the user want to , consider `c:\app-cache\images` every time the content reloaded , system checks out the images directory for the image that trying to load, if exists it shows the cached one , if not , it loads it from URL